# using the verb "comes" in a question

Tags: questions

I have written an question in form "Where an attribute comes from?". Immediately I realized that this is not grammatically correct and rewrote it to "Where an attribute does come from?" But I started to think why I wrote the question the first way. I have seen it before. Even when I wrote this question, StackExchange offers me question written similarly.

My question is whether it is possible (ok) to write such questions: "Where an attribute comes from?" and why.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Neither of them is the correct way IMO.

The proper way is...

> Where does an attribute come from?

As I'm advised by learned people in the language, the question is better with 'verb' separated (known as [Subject-Auxiliary Inversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject-auxiliary_inversion) as snailplain said). Having this said, *"What does he like?"* is preferred over *"What he likes?'*

Comment: I'm not sure that *What he likes?* is acceptable at all. *What likes he?* is "correct", but extremely archaic. *What does he like?* is normal.

Comment: @TRiG I was one of those Indians who practiced it! In India, it's damn common. Thanks to my dear native speakers! :)

Comment: Or, the question could be asked in the plural: _Where do attributes come from?_

Comment: Btw I just realized native speaker song in this form: "Who wants to live forever?". Do artists have special english rules?

Comment: Lyricists enjoy flexible grammar rules!